# Add attribute decorator to all classes in compilation time

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, decorator

In my solution I have a separate project for each level of tests. i.e. One for Unit Tests, one for Integration Tests and one for Acceptance Tests.
I want to be able to filter by TestCategory, but I don't want to be forced to add and maintain the TestCategory tag on each TestClass.
I was wondering if there is a way to add the class decorator in compile time and add the proper category depending on the project.

Comment: If you want to filter by project, can't you ask your test tool to only execute tests in a given assembly instead? And no, short of using something like Postsharp, there is no way to automatically apply an attribute to types or members in a project during compilation.

Comment: The short answer is I can't leverage the name filtering of test exeuction tool. The a bit longer answer is.. The tests are run in a build definition that is common for different projects (products) that may or may not have the same names for the test projects.

Comment: Well, then you're back to applying the attributes to all involved types/members. I haven't seen any such test tool that can look for those attributes on the assembly itself, typically I've seen name/namespace/assembly name filtering, or attribute filtering.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself. I need to add the attribute to every TestClass in every assembly.

Comment: I understood that. You need a tool like PostSharp to do that automatically, .NET or C# does not have any way of doing what you ask. But be aware that this is a X/Y problem. The attribute is Y, the solution to X, being able to correctly filter the tests. So if there is a different way of filtering that might solve your X problem, you should definitely look into that.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. For me the solution is actually in the way the filtering is done, but unfortunately that's out of my scope to change it.

Comment: Then unfortunately you must either employ a IL weaving tool, such as PostSharp (there are others as well), or just manually add the attributes to all the relevant classes.